# javascript to reverse order of values

Tags: javascript, string, reverse

How can I reverse the order of Duck, Donald with Javascript? 
I am currently retrieving Duck, Donald from a query string and I would like to be able to display it on the page, receiving it as Dondald Duck. 
I am using `document.write("Name: " + Request.QueryString("name"));` to write Duck, Donald to the page and I would also like to be able to change 'Mouse', 'Mickey G' to just 'Mickey Mouse'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var name = Request.QueryString("name").Item(1).split(",").reverse().join(" ").trim();
if(name.split(" ").length > 2) {
            name = name.split(" ");
            name.splice(1, 1);
            name = name.join(" ");     
} 
document.write(name);
```

Example at http://jsfiddle.net/6AdGs/

Comment: where would the document.write go? I tried: var name = Request.QueryString("name"); name = name.split(",").reverse().join(" ");  
   document.write("Name: " + Request.QueryString("name")); and it appears blank on the page

Comment: I wouldn't suggest using document.write as it's horrible practice, but I updated my answer.

Comment: @Will: So far you're right, but last line of your code is wrong, as now the string you've requested is processed using `split()`, you need to use `document.write("Name: "+name);` as variable `name` has modified string.

Comment: it still appears blank on the page when I used what you have above

Comment: Can you provide a working example of your program at jsfiddle.net?

Comment: here is an example: http://userpages.umbc.edu/~andrade1/querystring/querystring/example1%20-%20Copy.html the input boxes wouldn't be editable in the final version

Comment: The problem was that Request.QueryString didn't return a String. This version should work.

Comment: thanks it works is there anyway that I can get rid of a middle initial like Mouse, Mickey G? to become Mickey Mouse

Comment: You have to be a bit more specific then that, how sure are you that your names will only be in the format of "Firstname, Lastname" / "Firstname, middleInitial, LastName" and not in the format "Firstname firstname middlenameInitial, Lastname"?

Comment: very sure because I put them in so that they will only appear in the format lastname, firstname  and lastname, firstname middle inital. I just want to reverse the order on the page receiving the data and drop middle initials because they currently are not used on the second page

Comment: Updated the original answer again.

Comment: comes up blank http://userpages.umbc.edu/~andrade1/querystring/querystring/example1%20-%20Copy.html

Answer (score 2):

You can split the string using split method, and then past them in correct order:

```
var str = 'Duck, Donald';
var parts = str.split(',');
document.write(parts[1] + ' ' + parts[0]);
```

Basically thats what you need to do. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

This function may help you.

```
<script>
function reverseName(str) {
    var tail = str.substr(0, str.indexOf(","));
    var head = str.substr(str.indexOf(",") + 1);

    return head + ' ' + tail;
}

document.write("Name: " + reverseName(Request.QueryString("name")));
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

As above, but consider: Are first names and surnames always separated by commas? It becomes relevant with some non-English names you may find like 'Silva dos Santos, Miguel Jesus', where Silva dos Santos are the family names and Miguel Jesus are given names.